# Can you help me identify a vintage airplane in a painting?

Tags: aircraft-identification, spain

[image: King of Spain visiting spanish troops in Irak]

This is a recent photo of the king of Spain, Felipe VI, visiting Spanish troops stationed in Iraq. In the background there is a picture of an old plane, possibly with a propeller, that I suppose from WW2 era (more or less).

If that painting has been chosen to adorn a military installation located in Iraq and occupied by Spanish troops, I understand that it must be a type of historical significance for Spain or for Iraq.

Can anyone recognize it?

Comment: it could be a shared facility - the image may not necessarily be assumed to be entirely related to Spain

Comment: @NKCampbell ...as MikeSowsun's answer has shown... ;)

Comment: I was addressing the statement: "I understand that it *must* be a type of historical significance for Spain or for Iraq."

Comment: @NKCampbell Me too. I just found funny that I considered the possibility that it was an iconic plane for Spain and turned out to be a P-51 Mustang. :)

Answer (score 77, accepted):

The aircraft in the painting (I’m not sure it is a painting?) is a North American P-51C Mustang in the Tuskegee Airmen colors of the U.S. Air Force in WW II.

I cropped the image above and then used [TinEye Reverse Image Search](https://tineye.com/) to find the photo.

My search has expired on that website, but you can copy the “fuzzy” photo and try it yourself on the same site.

Search photo

[image]

Search Result

[image]

P-51C Mustang in Tuskegee Airmen (Minnesota wing of the Commemorative Air Force)
[image]
[image]

Comment: Well, a perfect answer. I used to wait a few hours before accepting them, but there's no doubt about it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: This is a fantastic answer, I just do not get the reverse search. You found the photo on which the painting was based? Or a (high resolution) photo of the painting? The planes are identical on the two first pictures (as far as I can tell from the blurry one). It must be a famous painting then, to have hi-res pictures of it (and not pictures which include it in the background, as in OP's case)

Comment: @WoJ, Who says that OP's picture is really a painting?  It could be a framed photograph.

Comment: @JPhi1618: I do not think that such photos were available at WW2 time (crisp, colors, ...)

Comment: @WoJ, its a recent photo of a classic, restored aircraft.  There are several operations around that keep WW2 aircraft maintained and operational for airshows and historic events.

Comment: @Ginasius better to wait a day.  SE folks are not paid staff, answer at leisure, and many of the smartest visit once a day.  You may have just missed them.  Although yes, this answer is unlikely to be bested!

Comment: @WoJ: Not only are the planes identical, but the *clouds* are as well.  Identical-looking aircraft from matching camera angles would be a possible coincidence, but matching clouds?  No way.

Comment: I voted this answer up not only due to the accurate answer, but because you show another tool how to search an image.

Comment: Your tineye says its expired

Comment: @JPhi1618 - ah right! I did not think about that possibility. Thanks, it all makes sense now.

Comment: My question would be➖why an American plane is in a painting or photo in that room in Iraq.

Comment: @WoJ Colour photography is much older than people realise: Kodak began selling Kodachrome colour film in 1935, and less convenient processes were commercially available even in 1907.

Comment: That room is in an American Military Base in Iraq. The Americans can hang anything they want on the walls.

Comment: @DavidRicherby: yes, I realize that. It is more the crispness of the photo and how colors are vivid which were not WW2-era like.